# ERROR - Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, deprecated, laravel, register-globals

Im occasionally getting this error, sometimes it pops up sometimes it doesnt:
ERROR - Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0

There was no php.ini file so i created one and turn register globals off, but that didn't work.
I added "php_flag register_globals 0" to the htaccess file, but that didn't work either…

Im using the laravel framework.

[Here is the link to the website, if you scroll through about 5 or so pages the error will occur](http://www.documentaryedge.org.nz/index.php/pages/6)

I have no more ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by that??

Comment: Ok I see iframe and some cookie code inside. So I assumed it can be exploit attempt. Also link was http://francis.outwin.natcoll.net.nz/pages/100 which is changed by now.

Comment: I accidentally posted the old link so i changed it to the new one.
The iframe is the video on the home page. 
You dont have any idea what the problem might be do you?

Comment: If you can edit question I can discard my down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP documentation:

```
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
```

So you either need to downgrade your PHP version to <=5.2 - or you need to remove any code that is using register globals.

> There was no php.ini file so i created one and turn register globals off

There is always a php.ini file. I'm guessing your are on a hosted solution somewhere, so you cannot see the ini file. You need to talk to your server administrator and get them to change it.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help. Its definitely a problem with my host, they have register_globals turned on by default and dont list the php.ini file to change this.