# Legacy PHP 5.2 where does $DOCUMENT_ROOT defined?

Tags: php

When migrating a legacy PHP 5.2 server, I stumble against this code in the `index.php`

```php
<?php
require_once("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/config.php");
// Other code
```

The `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` here act and behave just like the normal`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, which is very strange to me as I didn't see `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` defined anywhere.

This page is meant to be access by user and not called from other scripts, so the variable unlikely called in from other php files as well.

I am curious, is there some configuration on PHP 5.2 which makes it that the document root is specified in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT`? Or maybe it is some custom library we install that create this `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable?

Comment: It's not a standard PHP magic variable so there must be some code providing it. Perhaps there's an `extract($_SERVER);` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the `index.php` and suppose to be access by user at landing, and the first line already include the `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable. So I don't think it is `extract($_SERVER)`

Comment: Has the server been configured with an [auto_prepend_file](https://www.php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)?

Comment: [Substitute for $DOCUMENT_ROOT without register_globals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023844/substitute-for-document-root-without-register-globals)

Comment: [ERROR - Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846892/error-directive-register-globals-is-deprecated-in-php-5-3-and-greater-in-unk#:~:text=This%20feature%20has%20been%20DEPRECATED,that%20is%20using%20register%20globals.)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa does (did) `register_globals` expose things from `$_SERVER`? It's hard to find the documentation these days but from memory it was only request-based variables

Comment: Thanks, did not know it is possible auto prepend files. Just checked with `phpinfo()`, auto_prepend_file is not configured.

Comment: `register_globals` is indeed on! I tried in my local server and turn off `register_globals` and confirm this is the reason the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` can be use a variable. Thanks @steven7mwesigwa, can you post an answer so I accept it, cheers! Thanks @Phil as well for the insights!

Comment: @NgSekLong better to close as a duplicate of [Substitute for $DOCUMENT_ROOT without register_globals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69023844/283366)

Comment: Indeed, voted to closed